# DrawPrimitiveUP in d3d11

Tags: direct3d11

Just checking, but [it appears](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff476385%28VS.85%29.aspx) D3D9's DrawPrimitiveUP / any method of drawing WITHOUT a vertex buffer has been all but stripped out of D3D11.

Is there a way to draw in D3D11 that does *not* use a vertex buffer, with example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you have to use a vertex buffer